# JAVA: How many "mango trees" I can see with known height and position?

Tags: java

I have this problem that I want to solve with the help of java.
There are 6 "mango trees" in a orchard all in one line. Heights of these "mango trees" is fix but they are different positions ; for example 2nd tallest at first position, then smaller then tallest of all and so on...

I need to find how many I can see, for that I saved the positions in a `hashtable` with `<String, int>` pair. Then sorted it using `collections.sort` but that gave me only height in a order, not the position.

Whats the better approach to solve this problem?

What I tried:

```
Hashtable<String, Integer>tree = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    tree.put("first", 12);
    tree.put("second", 19);
    tree.put("third", 10);
    tree.put("fourth", 22);
    tree.put("fifth", 5);
    tree.put("sixth", 16);

    Vector vector = new Vector(tree.keySet());
    Collections.sort(vector);
    Iterator it = tree.keySet().iterator();

    it = vector.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       String element =  (String)it.next();
       System.out.println( element + " " + tree.get(element));
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @DavidPilkington I got a little excited, thinking I was going to learn about a new data structure. Alas.

Answer (score 1):

Save their heights in an `int` array `heights`, ordered by position; After that:

```
int maxH = 0, seen = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (heights[i] > maxH) {
    maxH = heights[i];
    seen++;
  }
}
```

`seen` variable is what you need

Comment: I dont know at which position which tree is standing.

Comment: In your code, you use `tree.put("first", 12")`. This means you know at which position it is. To use it with my code, define `heights` as `int[] heights = {12,19,10,22,5,16}`

Comment: I took an example, just take a real time scenario, if you are standing in front of many identical trees/pillars, would you be able to get position? You would only see a straight vertical line, height of this line would be height of tallest tree/pillar.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the tree list and keep storing the maximum height you've found till that moment. If the height of the tree is greater than the currently store value the tree is taller than the tallest you've seen till now and you increase the counter. If you meet a tree of maximum height you won't see anything behind it.

```
int maxHeight = 0;
int visibleTrees=0;
ArrayList<Integer> visiblePos = new ArrayList<Integer>;
for(int i=0; i<trees.size();i++){
    if(tree.height == maxTreeHeight){ visiblePos.add(i); visibleTrees++; break; }
    if(tree.height > maxHeight) { visiblePos.add(i); maxHeight = tree.height; visibleTrees++; }
}
```

Comment: and its place, first place or second place in row?

Comment: I modified the code so that it stores the positions of the visible trees in a list.

Answer (score 0):

create a class tree with tree_name,tree_position,tree_height and then sort on the basis of height and get the position and then apply your logic after that.